# Pattern Matching to create a new column in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a data table like the following:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(125534,"122-343",312343,"12343-343FGV", 1234, 713827), Product = c('Y', NA, NA, 'Z', NA, NA), Type = c(NA, 'D', 'G', NA, NA, NA)))

            ID Product Type 
1:       125534       Y   NA       
2:      122-343      NA    D      
3:       312343      NA    G      
4: 12343-343FGV       Z   NA     
5:         1234      NA   NA     
6:       713827      NA   NA
```

I would like to create a new column named CATEGORY based on how ID is categorized. 
My incorrect code looks like the following:

```
DF$CATEGORY <- ifelse(grepl("^12[0-9]|^31[0-9]|", DF$ID), 'IN', 'OUT')
```

Desired result:

```
            ID Product Type CATEGORY
1:       125534       Y   NA       IN
2:      122-343      NA    D      OUT
3:       312343      NA    G       IN
4: 12343-343FGV       Z   NA      OUT
5:         1234      NA   NA      OUT
6:       713827      NA   NA      OUT
```

I wanted to code it so that any ID with alphabetical letters or symbols, shorter than 6 characters and do not begin with either 12 or 31 are out. The remainder are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
DF[, CATEGORY := ifelse(grepl("[^0-9]", ID) | 
                          nchar(ID) < 6 | 
                          !grepl("^12|^31", ID), 
                        "OUT", "IN")]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this by creating the 'CATEGORY' column with "OUT" values and then specify the 'i' with logical index that only matches the criteria for "IN" cases and assign (`:=`) the 'CATEGORY' to "IN"

```
DF[, CATEGORY := "OUT"][grepl("^(12|31)[0-9]{4,}$", ID), CATEGORY := "IN"]
DF
#             ID Product Type CATEGORY
#1:       125534       Y   NA       IN
#2:      122-343      NA    D      OUT
#3:       312343      NA    G       IN
#4: 12343-343FGV       Z   NA      OUT
#5:         1234      NA   NA      OUT
#6:       713827      NA   NA      OUT
```